# Why is my Hill Orc apparantly no longer a priest?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

I'm playing a Hill Orc priest, and I noticed I haven't been gaining any orc followers at all. Up at the top right, my title says "Moop the Fighter" and not "Moop the Proselytizer" or whatever it normally says, and Smite is gone from my abilities list. I also can't train in invocations anymore.

What could have happened?

Comment: I haven't found anything authoritative as to the change, but believe it may have to do with the fact that the Priest class background was [removed in 0.13](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Priest).

Comment: @skovacs1 I'm playing 0.12.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Priest you need to keep in good standing with the chosen god. The "standing" is realized as "piety". If piety drops to zero, you lose the favour of your god.

Orcs worship Beogh. You can read up on what he appreciates and deprecates [here](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Beogh).

In short: Killing orc allies, desecrating dead orcs or destryoing orcish idols will lower your piety with Beogh. Perhaps you ate some orc corpses?

As Jack M found out himself, you also lose piety by using some of the skills granted by your god. Smite, for example, costs 3 piety according to the linked wiki page.

Comment: I have no idea what I did, but if that's the only explanation, that must be it.

Comment: Wait, Smiting doesn't decrease piety, does it?

Comment: erm, yes it does. Losing 3 piety is part of its costs.

Comment: Smite won't reduce your piety to zero, though - you'll lose access to Smite (until you get your piety back up) long before that happens.